# Adding easing to image pan

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using some JavaScript and jQuery (with the easing plugin) to create a virtual tour; really just a long image that can pan left and right. I have found this which is perfect for the cause: http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/1/. Is there a way to add easing to the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/MvRdD/890/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("https://raw.github.com/danro/easing-js/master/easing.min.js");
    var animateTime = 10,
        offsetStep = 5,
        scrollWrapper = $('#wrap');

    //event handling for buttons "left", "right"
    var aktiv;
    $('.bttL, .bttR').mousedown(function(e) {
        if (e.target.className === 'bttR') {
            aktiv = window.setInterval(function() {
                scrollWrapper.animate({
                    scrollLeft: '+=' + 20
                }, {
                    duration: 600,
                    queue: false,
                    easing: 'easeOutCirc'
                });
            }, 10);
        } else if (e.target.className === 'bttL') {
            aktiv = window.setInterval(function() {

                scrollWrapper.animate({
                    scrollLeft: '-=' + 20
                }, {
                    duration: 1200,
                    queue: false,
                    easing: 'easeOutCirc'
                });
            }, 10);

        }
    }).mouseup(function() {
        window.clearInterval(aktiv);
    });


    scrollWrapper.mousedown(function(event) {
        $(this).data('down', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollLeft', this.scrollLeft);
        return false;
    }).mouseup(function(event) {
        $(this).data('down', false);
    }).mousemove(function(event) {
        if ($(this).data('down')) {
            $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
                scrollLeft: $(this).data('scrollLeft') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX) * 2
            }, {
                duration: 600,
                queue: false,
                easing: 'easeOutCirc'
            });
        }
    }).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        $(this).stop(false, true).animate({
            scrollLeft: '-=' + delta * 60
        }, {
            duration: 400,
            queue: false,
            easing: 'easeOutCirc'
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }).css({
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'cursor': '-moz-grab'
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah no way, this is awesome! It does ease on the drag and mouse wheel but not on the button press?

Comment: That's now your part to learn a bit javascript :) If you fail in more than 30 minutes, just write again and I'll complete this part for you too :-*

Comment: It'll be tomorrow now but bear with me!

Comment: Okay, okay :) I've updated my answer! Be nice, vote up and mark this question as answered (if it is)...

Comment: It is! Cheers for that, This site has been a great help lately!

Comment: It's working well, however, do you know... Using Joomla! I'm looking to add multiple sliders to one page using anchors to link to them. I thought it would be simple to repeat the html css etc for each slider then in the javascript add 

     scrollWrapper = $('#panOne,#panTwo');

...

Comment: ...and what is the question now? How you could do that simpler? Use classes instead of IDs e.g. `#wrapper` => `#wrapper1, #wrapper2 etc.` and add the class `.wrapper` to each. In your script call them via `$('.wrapper')` then.

Comment: Yes I already had this kind of idea working and didn't like them scrolling together. Was shot down at the idea of a bulky page for loading times though with multiple sliders so I can use that idea now!